# Bitwise Operator with If Statement and comparison Operators. How does this if statement work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, bitwise-operators

```
a = 2
b = 1
if a == 2 | b == 1:
    print(a, b)
```

> this won't print the values of a & b

```
a = 2
b = 1
if ((a == 2) | (b == 1)):
    print(a, b)
```

> this will print the values

why so?

Comment: `a = 2
b = 1
if a == 2 or b == 1:
    print(a, b)
` Is this what you were intending?

Comment: No, actually the "bitwise-or" operator works differently and the "normal or" operator works differently.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these concepts thanks for introducing me!

Comment: No worries, I am also a newbie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator `==` in Python has a lower precedence than the operator `|`. So:

```
a == 2 | b == 1
```

is equivalent to:

```
a == (2 | b) == 1
```

which, in turn, is equivalent to:

```
(a == (2 | b)) and ((2 | b) == 1)
```

Given that `a==2`, at least one of the subexpressions must be false, regardless of `b`.

Answer (score 1):

`|` is the bitwise `OR` operator and it has higher precedence than `==`. So if brackets are not used, `2 | b` is executed at the start in the first program.

```
(2 | b) -> (2 | 1) -> (3)
```

Then when `a==3` is checked, it returns False, since `a=2`

I think you could use the `or` instead of `|` here if you want to to execute the statement by checking values of a and b.

Comment: Actually, the expression is false for _any_ `b`, as long as `a!=1`.